# Verifying if a set of vectors form a subspace of R3

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Would the set of vectors (a,b,2a-3b) form a subspace of R3? The zero vector (0,0,0) exists, and I think vector addition and scalar multiplication also hold. I can't think of how the axioms fail under this set.

Comment: If you can show that the set of all such vectors (i.e. $W := \{(a,b,2a-3b) \mid a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$) is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, contains the zero vector, and $\alpha x + \beta y \in W$ for each $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x,y \in W$, then you have that $W$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: I might be wrong, but do you personally think this set forms a subspace of R3?

Comment: I believe it does.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\{(a,b,2a-3b)\mid a,b\in\Bbb R\}=\{(a,0,2a)+(0,b,-3b)\mid a,b\in\Bbb R\}=\rm{span}\{(1,0,2),(0,1,-3)\}$, which is thus a ($2$-dimensional) vector space.

Answer (score 1):

There are just $3$ checks you need to make to determine whether a subset is a subspace.

$1$. Zero vector is in the set. In this case it is true.

$2$. The subset is closed under addition. Which means that for two vector $(a, b, 2a-3b)$ and $(x, y, 2x-3y)$ in the subset, the vector $(a+x, b+y, 2a+2x-3b-3y)$ is also in the subset. In this case, that is true as $$(a+x, b+y, 2a+2x-3b-3y)=(a+x, b+y, 2(a+x)-3(b+y))$$

$3.$ Make the last check yourself. This is the check where you have to show that for $\lambda \in R$ and $(a, b, 2a-3b)$ in the subset, we have that $$\lambda(a, b, 2a-3b)=(\lambda a, \lambda b, \lambda (2a-3b))$$ is also in the subset.

---

If all these conditions are true, then you can conclude that the given subset is a subspace.